# Conditions on F to be one-one and onto.....

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If I have a set A⊂X and f:P(X)⟶P(X)   defined by f(B)=A∩B.
What is the condition that make f is 1-1 and onto.

Its clear that all the non empty sets must have some non empty intersection with A,otherwise they would be mapped to phy and the function will not be one one any more.

Can anyone please help me with the other conditions?

Comment: "all nonempty sets must have some nonempty intersection with $A$" is an *extremely* strong condition on $A$; perhaps you should work it out in a tiny example (maybe $X$ has two or three elements)

Comment: "A" has to be the whole set?

Comment: HINT:  There must be some $B\subseteq A$ such that $f(B)=X$.

Comment: but if "A" is a proper subset of "X" then X intersection A will be A and A intersection A will be A so both will be mapped to A,making it not one-one.

Comment: @Brian M.Scott   am I right?

Comment: @Eric Stucky Am I right that "A" has to be the whole set.....

Comment: @jyoti: Yes, and it also won’t be onto if $A$ isn’t the whole set.